# Add Boolean value to an csv array with jq

Tags: json, csv, boolean, jq

I need to get a list of amazon images, and one of the values I need to show is a boolean value (true/false).

For example I can extract the Image IDs from the list I need to process without problem:

```
cat oneimage.json | jq -r '.Images[] | [.ImageId] | @csv'
"ami-000bd263d51e443f2"
```

But the next value I need to add to the list is a true/false value and jq chokes at the next command:

```
cat oneimage.json | jq -r '.Images[] | [.ImageId, ([.BlockDeviceMappings[].Ebs.DeleteOnTermination] | join(","))] | @csv'
jq: error (at <stdin>:89): string ("") and boolean (true) cannot be added
```

The json includes a list of volumes. The "DeleteOnTermination" value will be unique for each volume in the list and has to go into the same 'cell' in csv format.

The goal is to output the csv to a spread sheet and have all the DeleteOnTermination values separated by a comma on one line in a cell for each image.

Here is the json I'm using for this test:

```
{
"Images": [{
    "VirtualizationType": "hvm",
    "Description": "AB-P-RIDD-TRAN05-12-13-2018",
    "Hypervisor": "xen",
    "ImageId": "ami-000bd263d51e443f2",
    "State": "available",
    "BlockDeviceMappings": [{
            "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
            "Ebs": {
                "SnapshotId": "snap-0f1076dce3103833f",
                "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                "VolumeType": "gp2",
                "VolumeSize": 100,
                "Encrypted": false
            }
        },
        {
            "DeviceName": "/dev/sdi",
            "Ebs": {
                "SnapshotId": "snap-0c7d71a9d3887a048",
                "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                "VolumeType": "gp2",
                "VolumeSize": 5,
                "Encrypted": false
            }
        },
        {
            "DeviceName": "/dev/sdg",
            "Ebs": {
                "SnapshotId": "snap-00402196b9e023a72",
                "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                "VolumeType": "gp2",
                "VolumeSize": 10,
                "Encrypted": false
            }
        },
        {
            "DeviceName": "/dev/sdk",
            "Ebs": {
                "SnapshotId": "snap-05f65a62735de2846",
                "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                "VolumeType": "gp2",
                "VolumeSize": 20,
                "Encrypted": false
            }
        },
        {
            "DeviceName": "/dev/sdj",
            "Ebs": {
                "SnapshotId": "snap-0d350170b9d5c62bb",
                "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                "VolumeType": "gp2",
                "VolumeSize": 40,
                "Encrypted": false
            }
        },
        {
            "DeviceName": "/dev/sdh",
            "Ebs": {
                "SnapshotId": "snap-04679d09d89609e79",
                "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                "VolumeType": "gp2",
                "VolumeSize": 30,
                "Encrypted": false
            }
        },
        {
            "DeviceName": "/dev/sdf",
            "Ebs": {
                "SnapshotId": "snap-0b5f861fd93da6b20",
                "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                "VolumeType": "gp2",
                "VolumeSize": 5,
                "Encrypted": false
            }
        }
    ],
    "Architecture": "x86_64",
    "ImageLocation": "123456789191/AB-P-RIDD-TRAN05-12-13-2018",
    "RootDeviceType": "ebs",
    "OwnerId": "123456789191",
    "RootDeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
    "CreationDate": "2018-12-14T01:39:31.000Z",
    "Public": false,
    "ImageType": "machine",
    "Name": "AB-P-RIDD-TRAN05-12-13-2018"
}]
```

}

How can get the DeleteOnTermination value to appear in one csv cell, separated by commas with one DeleteOnTermination value for each volume?

Comment: Which version of jq are you using? On jq 1.6 your command works well.

Comment: I'm on version 1.5. I tried an apt-get update and it said it's the latest version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `tostring`.

```
.bool_value | tostring
```

Usage in your case:

```
jq -r '.Images[] | [.ImageId, ( [.BlockDeviceMappings[].Ebs.DeleteOnTermination | tostring] | join(",") )] | @csv' file
```

yields:

```
"ami-000bd263d51e443f2","true,true,true,true,true,true,true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a def of `join` that can be used with all extant versions of jq (that is, jq 1.3 and up), and which provides the flexible semantics of jq 1.6 (i.e. it only requires that all the items in the array be scalars):

```
def join(c):
  if length==0 then ""
  else reduce .[1:][] as $x (.[0]|tostring; . + c + ($x|tostring))
  end;
```

---

For ease of reference:

- `tostring` is available in all extant versions of jq;
- jq 1.3 does not have `join/1` (but it does have `@csv`).